# Scrapy :- pagination crawling is working fine but could not scrape the contents from next page onwards

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Having difficulty in **scraping** the data from next page , it is crawling the pages properly but same data is being scraped as from first page.

same behavior is observed from scrapy shell.

I am new to scrapy, code is given below. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import scrapy

class MostactiveSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mostactive'
    allowed_domains = ['finance.yahoo.com']

    # This Function is used for start url.
   
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active']
        for url in urls:
            print( url )
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_pages)

    # below function is used for page nevigation.
            
    def get_pages(self,response):
        count = str(response.xpath('//*[@id="fin-scr-res- 
        table"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/span').css('::text').extract())
        print('########## this is count ' + count)
        print (int(count.split()[-2]))
        total_results = int(count.split()[-2])       
        total_offsets = total_results // 25 + 1
        print ( '######### This is total offset %s '  %total_offsets )
        offset_list = [ i * 25 for i in range(total_offsets)]
        print ( ' ####### This is offset list %s ' % offset_list )
        for offset in offset_list:
            print ( ' ####### This is offset list in the for loop %s ' % offset )
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset= 
            {offset}', callback=self.get_stocks)
            print (f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset={offset}')
   
    #  below function is used for Content scraping for Tickers.

    def get_stocks(self, response):
        stocks= response.xpath('//*[@id="scr-res- 
        table"]/div[1]/table/tbody//tr/td[1]/a').css('::text').extract()
        print ('get stocks visited stocks on this page are %s ' %stocks )
        for stock in stocks:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}?p={stock}', 
            callback=self.parse)
            print(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}?p={stock}')

    # This below function is used for scrapping the content on the end page.

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
          'Price'  :  response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header- 
          info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]').css('::text').extract_first() ,
          'Change' :  response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header- 
          info"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[2]').css('::text').extract_first(),
          'Ticker' :  response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header- 
          info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1').css('::text').extract_first()
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: FYI scrap/scrapping are about thowing things away like rubbish - I think you mean __scrape__ and __scraping__

Comment: yes Barny you are right..I mean scrape.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty weird line breaks in your code. Everything works fine after fixing line break here:

```
for offset in offset_list:
    print ( ' ####### This is offset list in the for loop %s ' % offset )
    yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset={offset}', callback=self.get_stocks)
    print (f'https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset={offset}')
```

Comment: Actually this code works and scrapes first page results but could not scrape results from other pages...actual issue is if I pull the results from second page using screpy shell it shows the results from first page, not from the results from the second page. for ex scrapy shell https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=25&offset=75 this does not scrawl on this page instead it lands on the first page.

Comment: You're not right. Your code process ALL pages. See this [https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb8g5zriq8pqwga/Debug.txt?dl=0] file.